# OpenSSL Command Line Tool: "-in" argument from string

Tags: terminal, openssl

How can I trick the `-in` argument of the OpenSSL command line tool in order to get data from string instead a file?

Normally, I could use `echo` command to do it:

```
echo 'test string 1' | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -a -salt -pass pass:mypassword
```

Is there a way I can do it without `echo` and pipe? Similar to the `-pass pass:` argument?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a way to go around this! Instead of passing everything before and since openssl has an interactive mode, it's possible to run the command without input:

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -a -salt -pass pass:mypassword
```

And OpenSSL will be waiting for data to encrypt. This can be also useful for streams!

Then type in the string or data you want to encrypt and send a `EOT` (End of Transmission) in Terminal is usual `^D` `Control+D` it it will output to `stdout` the encrypted string!

Hope this may help someone some day!

Answer (score 6):

If your shell is bash and your OS supports it, you can use [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution):

```
openssl enc -in <(echo 'test string 1') -aes-256-cbc -a -salt -pass pass:mypassword
```

Comment: Hi, it works fine from my terminal, the problem is that I'm using NSTask in Objective-C to call the tool and that does not work there... thanks.

Comment: You can use "/bin/bash -c ..." to feed a command to bash.  This has other issues (shell metacharacters leading to security holes etc.), but it would let the process substitution work.

Comment: yes... "security holes" I'm using OpenSSL here... so as you might understand I care about having some security. (At least security provided by an NSPipe). Thanks.